# error CS0103: The name 'UserName' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, webforms

I'm trying to make a ASP.net identity auth system based on some code i found on Microsoft Developer Documents, and i keep getting this error! I have had it before with other code snippets from the site, and i don't know how i fixed the errors.
(The code snippets are from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project). )

I don't know how what to do, as i am not really that experienced with ASP.net.

ASPX File:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small">
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <h4 style="font-size: medium">Log In</h4>
       <hr />
       <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="LoginStatus" Visible="false">
          <p>
             <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="StatusText" />
          </p>
       </asp:PlaceHolder>
       <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="LoginForm" Visible="false">
          <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
             <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
             <div>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
             </div>
          </div>
          <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
             <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password</asp:Label>
             <div>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" />
             </div>
          </div>
          <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
             <div>
                <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="SignIn" Text="Log in" />
             </div>
          </div>
       </asp:PlaceHolder>
       <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="LogoutButton" Visible="false">
          <div>
             <div>
                <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="SignOut" Text="Log out" />
             </div>
          </div>
       </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CS File:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebFormsIdentity
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    StatusText.Text = string.Format("Hello {0}!!", User.Identity.GetUserName());
                    LoginStatus.Visible = true;
                    LogoutButton.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    LoginForm.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void SignIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
            var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
            var user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
                var userIdentity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, userIdentity);
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                StatusText.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
                LoginStatus.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        protected void SignOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            authenticationManager.SignOut();
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include code examples of what you have done.

Comment: Done. i'm sorry if im vague. i'm not really good at stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The solution was to change the namespace from the sample code's one to my namespace. Can't believe i didn't see that earlier.

Comment: Could you tell me how you fixed this?
I have this in my Site.master
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>
And in my other WebForm I have
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CompanyReports.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reports_CompanyReports" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
But I can not 
Do this:  logoutButton.Style["background-color"] = "red";
I get the error logoutButton does not exist in the current context